# Haskell Code with import Data.Char

Tags: haskell, char, numbers

I have to program a function which only accepts strings and counts my elements in a list, when it gets a number it has to count it as 1 and letters as 2. I don't know how to use `isNumber` after `import Data.Char`

```
import Data.Char

f1 [] = 0
f1 x = if x isNumber then (if True then 1 else False) else 2
f1 x = (head x) + sum (tail x)
```

Comment: `if True then 1 else False` will result in a *type conflict*...

Comment: how can i Bypass it? and how can i use isNumber in an if-the-else block?

Comment: Simplify `if True then x else y` to `x` ! You already know the "then" branch is being taken here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isNumber` is a function:

```
Prelude> import Data.Char
Prelude Data.Char> :t isNumber
isNumber :: Char -> Bool
```

So you use it like: `isNumber c` with `c` the character you want to test. Like:

```
Prelude Data.Char> isNumber '0'
True
Prelude Data.Char> isNumber 'a'
False
```

Now you can simply use a `sum` over a `map`ping:

```
f1 = sum . map helper
    where helper x | isNumber x = 1
                   | isLetter x = 2
                   | otherwise = 0
```

Here we defined a `helper :: Char -> Int` where we use guards to map numbers on `1`, letters on `2` and all other elements (spacing, punctuations,...) on zero.

This for instance generates:

```
*Main> f1 "Foo123"
9
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,  now I have only one Problem

Comment: parse error on input `:'
        Failed, modules loaded: none.

Comment: import Data.Char
        Data.Char> :t isNumber 
        isNumber :: Char -> Bool
        helper :: Char -> Int

       f1 = sum . map helper 
            where helper x | isNumber x = 1
                              | isLetter x = 2
         | otherwise = 0

Comment: @Tou: you know instead of just coping the code, it would be useful if you first read the answer...

Answer (score 2):

One other way might be using the [`foldl`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#g:3) with a helper function as follows;

```
helper :: Int -> Char -> Int
helper n c | isNumber c = n + 1
           | otherwise  = n + 2

getsum :: String -> Int
getsum = foldl helper 0

*Main> getsum "test123"
11
```